# Select elements which are neither disabled nor readonly

Tags: javascript, jquery, selector

I am trying to select elements which are not disabled as well as not readonly. Currently I am using $(".data-fields.active").serializeArray(); but apparently it seems to filter out disabled but returning elements which are readonly. How can I filter out those too?

Answer (score 0):

This should work using [`:not()`](https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) selector like:

```
$(".data-fields.active:not([readonly])").serializeArray();
```

DEMO:

```js
const arr = $(".data-fields.active:not([readonly])").serializeArray();
console.log( arr )
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="data-fields active" name="name1" value="1"><br>
<input type="text" class="data-fields active" name="name2" value="2"><br>
<input type="text" class="data-fields active" name="name3" value="3" readonly=""><br>
<input type="text" class="data-fields active" name="name4" value="4" readonly=""><br>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply , I used it but it is not returning anything.
I am new to ui.

Comment: Sure. Can you please add a small demo with html inputs where few are active, few are readonly and then we can try to reproduce the issue.

Comment: I have also added a demo. You can there are 4 inputs: 2 are enabled and other two are read-only and the `arr` variable returns the data for enabled inputs only.

Comment: <input is="coral-textfield" class="coral3-Textfield coral-InputGroup-input" type="text" handle="input" role="textbox" tracking="off" readonly="" id="coral-id-29" aria-labelledby="label_b08014af-dcbd-497f-b90f-16c8992b7f4c" aria-invalid="false">

Comment: Sorry I am not able to see the demo.

Comment: Apparently it seems to work for $(".data-fields.active:not([disabled])").serializeArray(); but not for readonly.

Comment: Not sure what's the issue happening on your end. Is this demo here working for you atleast?